# Numpy 3d arrays - Switch from for-loop to numpy method

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 3D numpy arrays which represent two images. The shape of each array is (1080, 1920, 3). The number 3 represents the RGB value of each pixel in the image.

The code below replaces every non-black pixel in the first array to the value of the "parallel" pixel (in the same index) from the other array.:

```
        def replace_nonblack_pixels(first_array, second_array):
            mask = first_array.sum(axis=2) < BLACK_THRESHOLD # = 0.01
            for i in xrange(first_array.shape[2]):
                first_array[:, :, i] = (first_array[:, :, i] * mask) + ((1 mask) * second_array[:, :, i])
```

The thing is that i want to speed up the code by using only numpy methods and not python for-loops. Someone told me to use `numpy.ma` but i don't know anything about it.

Waiting for your answers, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
m = np.where(mask)
first_array[m[0],m[1],:] = second_array[m[0],m[1],:]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for replying. I will check it soon :)

Comment: Sorry wen i tried it the first couple times i was using a random generator and all my pixels gave a false condition for the mask. I've edited the code to take into account that np.where gives 2 arrays which do no expand automatically

Comment: Also on a side note in your code i think you inverted the conditions on the mask. The first one should be (1-mask) and the second should be mask, since the mask is True(1) where you actually want to replace the pixels

Comment: Your code works but it is not faster.. Can you think about a solution which will be faster?

Comment: This might be one of those tasks that doesn't get sped up by collapsing a loop into numpy splicing and broadcasting. It does make sense since the numpy speeding up comes when particular methods are used to do basic operations on arrays by taking the entire chunks of binary data all at once. In this case i think numpy still need to access every element designated by the mask 1 by one in both array and do the replacement

Comment: You could try to check if there is at-least a slight improvement by using a huge starting array, but i wouldn't expect much, since what you save by skipping the whole matrix multiplication might be lost inside the numpy.where.  You should also consider that the generation of the mask might be relevant in time performance, and that is the same between the 2 implementations

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your explanation and dedication of time, you helped me a lot!